# How to solve this task in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, for

How to `x1` return back in for loop and plot `xt`?

```
xt = 1 x1[[1]] = xt For[i = 2, i < 4, i++, xt = x1[[i - 1]];
    x1 = xt + 2;
    Print[x1]
  ]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You are accessing parts of `x1`. Could you please provide a definition for it as well? Please include the desired outcome to your post. Thanks.

Comment: When collecting results from a `For` loo, your best chance is often with `Table`. If you want a more functional approach, xou can take a look at `FoldList`

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the specifics of your question.  Also, use semicolons as needed.... you're breaking syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Perhaps you meant

```
xt = 1;
x1[1] = xt;
For[i = 2, i < 4, i++,
 xt = x1[i - 1];
 x1[i] = xt + 2;
 Print[x1[i]]]

(* 3

   5 *)
```

More succinctly (using recursion with [`memoization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html)),

```
Clear[x1]

x1[1] = 1;
x1[i_] := x1[i] = x1[i - 1] + 2;

x1 /@ Range[3]

(* {1, 3, 5} *)
```

Looking at stored values,

```
?? x1
```

[image]

Using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) or [`RSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolveValue.html) for a general solution for any `i`

```
Clear[x1, i]

x1[i_] = RSolveValue[{x1[1] == 1, x1[i] == x1[i - 1] + 2}, x1[i], i]

(* -1 + 2 i *)

x1 /@ Range[3]

(* {1, 3, 5} *)
```